# how to store large medical images in a database online?

Tags: database, image, large-file-upload

Is it possible to store large images 1go to 2go medical images by uploading them to a mongobd database online?

the database is consulted by a doctor, who has the right to see the info about his patients.

what needs to be done to make the operation fast?

and how many ressources do I need to make this possible on a private server?

or is the cloud solution the only possibility?

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you mean by the database? Any RDBMS? What does it mean quickly? It's about writing to the database or about transfer or something else? What is easy? What did the cloud requests come from? Please specify the question.

Comment: mongodb database, transfering the large data to the database easy as in easy to upload and read the large data from the database. about the cloud solution there is this one https://www.itnonline.com/content/easy-patient-uploading-medical-images-and-information

Comment: I would like to help you but you have asked too many general questions at once and the whole is unclear. The database itself will not do anything, you need an application that will manage access and write / read from the database. You can do it in many ways. The answer to the next questions depends on what you choose. I think you should first design such an application and then consider the technical details and choose technologies.

Comment: thank you, Apparently you need to use GridFs a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB, I don't know the limite of the file size accepted by GridFs, I need to look more into this. I just need a really good internet connection to upload pictures to an load from the database. I'll update the question when I run into problems during the dev of the application.